# Correct way to implement standard __new__ in Python

Tags: python

What is the correct way to implement the standard behaviour of `__new__` in Python so that no functionality is broken?

I used

```
class Test:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

t=Test()
```

which on some Python versions throws DepreciationWarnings. On the internet I had seen something with `super()` or with `type()`. What are the differences and which is prefered?

Comment: Python 3.2 for me. Python 3.1 for some colleagues which will switch soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should write

```
return super(Test, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

This is recommended by [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) (and [the same for 2.x](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)).

The reason to use `super` is as always to cope with inheritance tree linearisation; you don't know for certain that the appropriate superclass is `object`, so you should always use `super`.

Comment: I don't have a python interpreter at the moment to test it, but in Python3 `super().__new__` should work as well I assume?